# Embedding Schwarzschild in FRLW

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, black-holes, metric-tensor, space-expansion

Does there exist an exact metric in the literature for embedding the Schwarzschild metric in the Friedmann–Lemaître–Robertson–Walker metric? If so, please give a good reference. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Schwarzschild metric in expanding Universe](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/282165/)

Comment: I flagged this as a duplicate. See: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/282165/